# Plotting a bar/colum plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, geom-bar, geom-col

I am trying the following plotting.

I have this data set:

```
Pathway   Value    Col.Code
AKTSig        1         r
HRAS          2         r
Lbind         3         h
GPCRact       4         r
ACHsig        5         h
ACEest        -2        r
MRNAspl       -3        h
Notch         -4        h
Delta         -5        r
Sonic         -6        r
```

I would like to plot a graph that has these columns with pathway along the x axis, value up the y axis and the columns coloured by the Col.Code column. I have tried geom_col() from ggplot2 but this always rearranges the columns into a random order i.e. not highest value to most negative. I have also tried geom_bar() but this creates counts for the pathways and doesn't plot what I have described above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
library(dplyr)

ggplot(data,aes(x=reorder(Pathway,-Value),y=Value,fill=Col.Code))+geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image]

Comment: Beat me to it. But I had used `levels = stringr::str_sort(df1$Pathway, numeric = TRUE)` in the coercion to factor.

Comment: Sorry, I think I made my example data too simple. I called the pathways 'P1, P2...' etc but they actually have long character names which are super annoying. I have tried both of your codes and I think this is why they don't work :( Please can you help me out again? Sorry for not being more clear when I wrote the first post!

Comment: @TobiasFirth Nice, so could you add real values for pathway? I will add an update.

Comment: @Duck, Hi, I made the edits,  sorry for not being clearer the first time around. Just while I'm here, is there a more efficient way to add example tables to the question without tying them out manually? Best wishes, Tobi

Comment: @TobiasFirth Updated now, please check if it helps!

Comment: @IanCampbell Yes, thanks! I thought it was the order of labels. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

One other approach is with `fct_reorder` from the `forcats` package:

```
library(forcats)
ggplot(data,aes(x=fct_reorder(Pathway,-Value),y=Value,fill=Col.Code)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
  labs(x = "Pathway")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I just tried this and it worked perfectly. Thank you!